# Laravel - calling a page fragment from another controller (in a bundle)

Tags: php, laravel, hmvc

I'm not sure if I'm going about things completely wrong here. But essentially what I want to be able to do is call a function within one of my bundles from my main application controller, is this kind of behaviour possible in Laravel.

The actual situation is that I have my home controller in /application/controllers/home.php which looks like this:

```
class Home_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public function action_index()
    {       
            $blog = ?;
            return View::make('common.html_template')->with($blog, 'blog');
    }
}
```

I have also built a blog bundle with a controller in /bundles/blog/controllers/home.php which looks like this:

```
class Blog_Home_Controller extends Base_Controller {

    public function get_latest()
    {
        //bit of code here
    }
}
```

Is it possible to load the contents of get_latest to my $blog variable as a page fragment, or am I approaching this incorrectly.

Comment: Laravel you say? http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/46607/laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if it is possible, your approach is wrong according to MVC approach. A controller should not be aware of another controller. If you need to get some data from somewhere try using library or model instead of a controller, or you can implement `get_latest()` method in the `Home_Controller`

Comment: I know what you are saying and I do want to respect the mvc approach within my bundles, but I am looking to have my application folder co-ordinate/call the various bundles and act as a layout/view override where necessary. I considered putting get latest in the home controller but would prefer to keep it in with the module/bundle and just make a call to it if at all possible. I've seen an hmvc bundle - maybe I'll check that out